# Sign Up with Facebook and Twitter SDK for iOS

Tags: facebook, ios6, twitter, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to add Facebook and Twitter login and sign up in my iOS app. As my App is server based, I need to create a user profile on my DataBase as well. But the problem is that I cannot fetch passwords from Facebook and Twitter for obvious reasons. So I am not sure how to go about it. What should be used as a password for the new profiles that are created, and then log the users in as well.

What have people done in past to create profiles on their databases by fetching information from Facebook and Twitter?

I want to save the Email address, Name, Location, Interests, and then also a password. What should be the right way of going about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access that information of course. The way it works is Facebook or Twitter sending you a response saying "Yes, credentials are OK for user XXXXXX" Or "No, bad credentials". Then you can save the user's ID to your database.

You will never get any other info unless you ask for permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter

To ask permissions, you will have to create an app.

[How to ask for permission in facebook application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006114/how-to-ask-for-permission-in-facebook-application)

Comment: JoRousss, I did gather that once I read the documentation. But once I create a user profile in my database using name,emails,etc. Based on that, I can easily assign the user a username, but what about password? should I make the password the access token? Is it device independent until it expires?

Comment: You can't set a password, you have to get the user to log in using facebook again

Comment: There must be a unique user ID you can save so you know the same user logged in again

Comment: JoRouss, but I also need to create a user profile on my Database, and since authentication of the user profile at my database requires a password, I am not sure how to get around that situation

Comment: Forget the password, let Facebook tell you if the user is logged in or not

Comment: Somebody, I will try to implement this. But I am still having troubles grasping the concept. can you please maybe share an ios 6 FB/Twitter integration example with me? or maybe a tutorial that I can probably look into?

Comment: I don't have such a project at home. The concept is : you don't bother about the credentials stuff, you let facebook take care of it. You accossiate your profile info with the unique user ID facebook will return you once the user is logged in (will always be the same). So you know the 2 essensial things, is he connected, and who is he.

Comment: @Jonathan You can download the [FacebookSDK](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-3.5.pkg) and look at the Scrumptious example.

Comment: I would also add that some of the items you want, like [Email](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) require extended permissions.

Comment: @MichaelKellyReneer for iOS 6 we do not need to download Facebook SDK anymore

Comment: That is not true, please refer to the Getting Started [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/).